# Can't deploy Java EE Application to Wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink, wildfly

im trying to migrate from Glassfish AS to WildFly AS.

After I created the JDBC Datasource in Wildfly and changed the persistnce.xml accordingly i get this error on deploy:

server.log:

```
2014-04-10 10:34:26,496 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.2.0.Final
2014-04-10 10:34:26,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
2014-04-10 10:34:26,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS012615: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
2014-04-10 10:34:26,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
2014-04-10 10:34:26,601 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
2014-04-10 10:34:26,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
2014-04-10 10:34:26,612 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
2014-04-10 10:34:26,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
2014-04-10 10:34:26,729 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-7)     JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.3.Final)
2014-04-10 10:34:26,744 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7)     JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Final starting
2014-04-10 10:34:26,612 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
2014-04-10 10:34:26,770 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path C:\Users\xy\Desktop\wildfly2/welcome-content
2014-04-10 10:34:26,742 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Final
2014-04-10 10:34:26,776 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
2014-04-10 10:34:26,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
2014-04-10 10:34:26,813 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.20.Final
2014-04-10 10:34:26,823 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7)     JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
2014-04-10 10:34:26,841 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7)     JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
2014-04-10 10:34:26,850 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5)     JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2014-04-10 10:34:26,859 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
2014-04-10 10:34:27,117 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:/jdbc/Application]
2014-04-10 10:34:27,194 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3)     JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on /127.0.0.1:8080
2014-04-10 10:34:27,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory     C:\Users\xy\Desktop\wildfly2\standalone\deployments
2014-04-10 10:34:27,201 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4)     JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "bg-application-1.0.war" (runtime-name: "bg-application-1.0.war")
2014-04-10 10:34:27,309 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2014-04-10 10:34:27,448 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final
2014-04-10 10:34:29,406 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6)     JBAS016017: Found both WEB-INF/beans.xml and WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml. It is not portable to use both locations at the same time. Weld is going to use the former location for this deployment.
2014-04-10 10:34:29,610 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for Application
2014-04-10 10:34:30,019 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "bg-application-1.0.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"bg-application-1.0.war#Application\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.Application]"]}
2014-04-10 10:34:30,067 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29)     JBAS018559: Deployed "bg-application-1.0.war" (runtime-name : "bg-application-1.0.war")
2014-04-10 10:34:30,069 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)     JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.Application (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."bg-application-1.0.war#Application"] 

2014-04-10 10:34:30,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2014-04-10 10:34:30,221 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2014-04-10 10:34:30,222 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.0.0.Final "WildFly" started (with errors) in 5908ms - Started 202 of 253 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 82 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2014-04-10 10:34:30,383 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2)     JBAS015877: Stopped deployment bg-application-1.0.war (runtime-name: bg-application-1.0.war) in 72ms
2014-04-10 10:34:30,725 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2)     JBAS018558: Undeployed "bg-application-1.0.war" (runtime-name: "bg-application-1.0.war")
2014-04-10 10:34:30,727 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2)     JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.persistenceunit."bg-application-1.0.war#Application" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."bg-application-1.0.war".POST_MODULE] 

2014-04-10 10:34:35,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found bg-application-1.0.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called bg-application-1.0.war.dodeploy
2014-04-10 10:35:12,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6)         JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "bg-application-1.0.war" (runtime-name: "bg-application-1.0.war")
2014-04-10 10:35:16,972 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6)     JBAS016017: Found both WEB-INF/beans.xml and WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml. It is not portable to use both locations at the same time. Weld is going to use the former location for this deployment.
2014-04-10 10:35:16,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for Application
2014-04-10 10:35:17,345 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ({"deployment" => "bg-application-1.0.war"}) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"bg-application-1.0.war#Application\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.jdbc.Application]"]}
2014-04-10 10:35:17,349 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2)         JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "bg-application-1.0.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"bg-application-1.0.war#Application\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.jdbc.Application]"]}
2014-04-10 10:35:18,696 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7)         JBAS015877: Stopped deployment bg-application-1.0.war (runtime-name: bg-application-1.0.war) in 1347ms
2014-04-10 10:35:18,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2)         JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.jdbc.Application (missing) dependents:     [service jboss.persistenceunit."bg-application-1.0.war#Application"] 
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.Application (no longer required)

2014-04-10 10:54:57,813 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 7)     JBAS014900: Content added at location C:\Users\xy\Desktop\wildfly2\standalone\data\content\bd\45d5d7e308fcffae0443c0bda8783997978d52\content
2014-04-10 10:54:57,818 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "bg-application-1.0.war" (runtime-name: "bg-application-1.0.war")
2014-04-10 10:55:02,312 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016017: Found both WEB-INF/beans.xml and WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/beans.xml. It is not portable to use both locations at the same time. Weld is going to use the former location for this deployment.
2014-04-10 10:55:02,327 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for Application
2014-04-10 10:55:03,145 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52)     JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'bg-application-1.0.war#Application'
2014-04-10 10:55:03,464 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) Failed to define class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.Helper in Module "deployment.bg-application-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.<init>(Finalizer.java:85) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.register(Finalizer.java:90) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.lang.Object.<init>(Object.java:37) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.io.InputStream.<init>(InputStream.java:45) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.<init>(ZipFile.java:659) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:356) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:409) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at org.jboss.vfs.spi.JavaZipFileSystem.openInputStream(JavaZipFileSystem.java:186) [jboss-vfs-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.openStream(VirtualFile.java:258) [jboss-vfs-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.VFSResourceLoader$2.run(VFSResourceLoader.java:133)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.VFSResourceLoader$2.run(VFSResourceLoader.java:124)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.VFSResourceLoader.getClassSpec(VFSResourceLoader.java:124)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:252) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4667) [eclipselink-2.6.0-M2.jar:2.6.0.v20130815-a4708b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4639) [eclipselink-2.6.0-M2.jar:2.6.0.v20130815-a4708b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4615) [eclipselink-2.6.0-M2.jar:2.6.0.v20130815-a4708b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.log(AbstractSession.java:4564) [eclipselink-2.6.0-M2.jar:2.6.0.v20130815-a4708b6]
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:127) [eclipselink-2.6.0-M2.jar:2.6.0.v20130815-a4708b6]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.classloader.JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:48) [wildfly-jpa-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(DelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:60)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:415) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final]
```

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Application" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/Application</jta-data-source>
    <!--<properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="True" />
        </properties>-->
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The subsystem part in the standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/Application" pool-name="Application" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://**:3306/test</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>test</user-name>
                        <password>**</password>
                    </security>
                   <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

Can anybody help me?
After hours of googling im stuck.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You are getting a java.lang.StackOverflowError when trying to load a JPA provider class.  I Can't say what the problem is, but its not likely to do with the driver.  How have you added EclipseLink to the server path?  The stack itself doesn't seem large, so you might want to check the server startup settings to be sure it starts up with enough resources

Comment: The issue looks the same as this one https://gist.github.com/miere/6979148 with no solution posted.  You might try adding the <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss"/> property, but I'd ask in the server forum if it doesn't work, as it looks like a classloader issue.

Answer (score 0):

try out `<non-jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/Application</non-jta-data-source>` in your persistence.xml since you've set the jta-property of your datasource declaration to false.