# stackoverflow while integrating eclipselink with jboss eap 6

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to deploy an application configured with eclipse link as jpa provider on jbosss eap 6.3
but it seems there is an issue between EclipseLink and jboss because i get a stackoverflow error while deploying

```
Failed to define class org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.WeaverLogger in Module "deployment.test-service.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_74]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.VFSResourceLoader.getClassSpec(VFSResourceLoader.java:131) [jboss-as-server-7.4.1.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.4.1.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:268) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.classloader.JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(JPADelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:48) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.1.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.4.1.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DelegatingClassFileTransformer.transform(DelegatingClassFileTransformer.java:60) [jboss-as-server-7.4.1.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.4.1.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:474) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.4.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:100)
```

Do i need to add some configuration to jboss(standalone.xml)?

There is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://*****" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*****" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****" />

            <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>                
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My pom.xml(this project will be a dependency of another)

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-app</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <relativePath>../test-app</relativePath>
        </parent>
        <artifactId>test-repository</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Any advices will be appreciated
Thank you very much

Comment: Its not clear how much stack you have available for your JVM, as there is only 1 line of EclipseLink code in the error stack.  Try expanding the memory for your container, or you can weave your application upfront statically https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

Comment: It could be related to other stackoverlow exceptions posted on Jboss/wildfly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983164/cant-deploy-java-ee-application-to-wildfly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983164/cant-deploy-java-ee-application-to-wildfly    It could also be related to https://developer.jboss.org/thread/237357?start=0&tstart=0&_sscc=t which indicates the eclipselink.archive.factory system property needs to be set as described at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much man . Your help was really valuable and precious !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Chris** answer , i managed to run jboss eap 6 and EclipseLink by integrating eclipse link module inside jboss eap

I needed to create a new folder : JBOSS_ HOME\modules\org\eclipse\persistence\main and copy eclipselink.jar inside.  Then i needed to create the module.xml associated

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.eclipse.persistence">
   <resources>
      <resource-root path="eclipselink.jar" />
   </resources>
   <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.api" />
      <module name="javax.persistence.api" />
      <module name="javax.transaction.api" />
      <module name="javax.validation.api" />
      <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" />
      <module name="org.antlr" />
      <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" />
      <module name="org.dom4j" />
      <module name="org.javassist" />
      <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
   </dependencies>
</module>
```

Complete tutorial : https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UsingEclipseLink and http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/jboss002.htm

Moreover despites my server ran smoothly after that but i got a new error after trying persisting any data "object is not a known entity type"

The problem was because in the persistence.xml i had the line   `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>`

It seems there is a classloading issue between eclipselink and jboss eap

I needed to declare explicitely entities by `<class>` attributes